# get a value from firestore array contains

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I can only get the values I need from the array if I added a string such "اقلام", "سبورة" or any other string value, however, I want the value to be passed a prop from another component or screen. is there away to handle this issue?

[image]

```
const fetchCategoryProducts = (catId)=>{
    const categoryProductsCollection = query(collection(db, "Product"), where("categories", "array-contains", catId))
    const getCategoryProducts = getDocs(categoryProductsCollection);
    const categoryProducts = (await getCategoryProducts).docs.map(item=>{
        const data = item.data();
        data.id = item.id;
        return data
    })
    console.log(categoryProducts) // getting empty array here
}}
```

Comment: What is the value of `catId`?

Comment: the value is a string passed a prop from another component. the value of the string is one of the values included in the array. i tested it with just a string instead of the catId, and it works fin, but when i pass the catId from another componenets i get empty array

Comment: Are you sure it's the same string? Maybe you should consider calling trim().

Comment: _"but when i pass the catId from another componenets i get empty array"_ In that case, can you share your complete code including the parent components as well so we can see what's wrong? Also `console.log(catId)` and share the output.

Comment: @AlexMamo this is how it works const fetchCategoryProducts = ({catId})=>{   const categoryProductsCollection = query(collection(db, "Product"), where("categories", "array-contains", catId.trim())). thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my question:

> What is the value of `catId`?

And your answer:

> The value of the string is one of the values included in the array. I tested it with just a string instead of the `catId`, and it works fin, but when I pass the `catId` from other components I get an empty array.

If the code works with the hardcoded value, then most likely the value in the database contains some white spaces and for that, you have to use `trim()`:

```
const fetchCategoryProducts = (catId)=>{
    const categoryProductsCollection = query(collection(db, "Product"), where("categories", "array-contains", catId.trim()))
    const getCategoryProducts = getDocs(categoryProductsCollection);
    const categoryProducts = (await getCategoryProducts).docs.map(item=>{
        const data = item.data();
        data.id = item.id;
        return data
    })
    console.log(categoryProducts)
}}
```